# Phusion passenger is overriding my database config

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, phusion

I am using nginx with Phusion Passenger to bootload a ruby on rails application, if I run the application like

```
rails s -e production
```

It does connect correctly to the database, but when bootloaded from nginx with passenger it tries to use root to the database, like ignoring the config files.

I already tried giving permissions, but doesnt look like there is the problem, I already opened the 3 possible host names for root, which could be "localhost", "%" and "127.0.0.1", but in any case it should be openning a connection with root

I would say something is weird on how passenger behaves or that somewhere (not in the app) is ignoring the database.yml or overriding the credentials

Comment: If you're using Passenger then this is a very strange way to be launching your application. Does your `database.yml` have root configured for anything? On a production server it should have `production` and only production as a top-level key.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion, I think you should try [Passenger Standalone](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/deploy/ruby/) that is what I use and it works fine.